# What size are ROM banks in the iNES format?

Tags: file-format, nintendo

According to the [iNES documentation](http://fms.komkon.org/EMUL8/NES.html#LABM), ROM banks are 16kB.

Is this 16000 bytes (16 kB) or 16384 bytes (16 KiB) per ROM bank? I couldn’t find this anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: AFAIK, memory chips are always in ^2, so 16384 is a pretty safe guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

16384B - the memory banks are individually adressable ROM chips, which means they need to fill in complete address space of their relevant column select lines.

Bottom line - digital hardware always uses 2^x, at least till 1990s when marketoids decided to pimp up drive sizes.